# Haskell Error in List

Tags: list, haskell

I dont know what is wrong with my code, I just want to get a list and fill it up properly and return that list as a result of that function. could you help me to solve this problem?

```
 fill  [] counter= []
 fill  (x:xs) counter= do
                   (if x==0  
                   then do
                       let new =counter+1
                       new:xs
                       fill xs new
                   else 
                       fill xs counter)
```

I want to fill the zeros with non repeated numbers

```
  main = do 
 fill [9,0,9,0,0,0] 0   -- expexted to get [9,1,9,2,3,4]
```

Comment: What do you want to fill the list with?

Comment: I don’t understand the logic here. If you want `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, use `[1..4]`.

Comment: Do you expect `fill [0,0,0,0] 0 == [0,1,2,3]` ?

Comment: I just want to fill the zeros with non repeated numbers

Comment: SHiNKiROU explained why it doesn’t work. Seems like you want something along the lines of `fill [] _ = []` `fill (0:xs) counter = counter : fill xs (counter + 1)` `fill (x:xs) counter = x : fill xs counter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing Haskell as if it's an imperative language. The second expression in the `do` block, `new:xs`, does nothing at all.

The do block after `then`

```
do
  let new =counter+1
  new:xs
  fill xs new
```

Because `do`s and `let`s actually translate to lambdas:

```
let x = a
b x
```

becomes

```
(\x -> b x)(a)
```

, your `do` block translates to:

```
(\new -> (\discarded -> fill xs new)(new:xs) ) (counter + 1)
```

and `new:xs` is discarded in the middle.

Do notation is only useful if you are dealing with monads. Otherwise, it leads to misleading code.

See also:

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_Notation
- http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Do_notation_considered_harmful

Answer (score 1):

We could a bit modify original version:

```
fillZero' (z:zs) y'@(y:ys) = 
         if z == 0 
         then y : fillZero' zs ys
         else z : fillZero' zs y'
fillZero' _ _ = []
```

and use:

```
fillZero = flip fillZero' [1..]

> fillZero [0,305,0,0,0,8,0,0]
[1,305,2,3,4,8,5,6]
```